# Nested trait in class constructor in scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I'm playing around with scala (scala 2.8).  Suppose I have a class with a nested trait, and want to use that nested trait as the type for a parameter in the class's constructor.  Is that even possible?  This is the closest I've come:

```
class OuterClass(traitParam:OuterClass#InnerTrait) {
  trait InnerTrait { }
  val y:InnerTrait = traitParam
}
```

Without the third line that even compiles, but as soon as I try to actually use the `traitParam` as an `InnerTrait` I get a compiler error:

> type mismatch; found: OuterClass#InnerTrait required: OuterClass.this.InnerTrait.

I can't figure out what (if anything) I could do.  Doing

```
class OuterClass(traitParam:OuterClass.this.InnerTrait)
```

instead, as the error message might suggest, does not compile.  Do I have any choice other than to move `InnerTrait` outside of `OuterClass`?  If you're wondering why I would want to do this, the answer is that in my actual code, the equivalent of `OuterClass` has type parameters which would then be used in `InnerTrait`.  If I move it outside, then I have to restate the type parameters every time I reference the inner trait.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're encountering Scala's *path-dependent types*. your `val y: InnerTrait`'s type is specific to the instance in which it's contained. `OuterClass#InnerTrait` is a supertype of all the `InnerTrait` extant for all instances of `OuterClass`.

Try working with this:

```
class OuterClass(traitParam: OuterClass#InnerTrait) {
    trait InnerTrait { }

    type IT = OuterClass#InnerTrait

    def m1: IT = traitParam
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> OuterClass has type parameters which
>   would then be used in InnerTrait

So it is possible to have `a: OuterClass` and `b: OuterClass` such that these type parameters are different. For instance:

```
abstract class OuterClass[T] {
  val x: T
}

val a = new OuterClass[Int] { val x = 5 }
val b = new OuterClass[String] { val x = "abc" }
```

So here is the conundrum... `InnerTrait` must be tied to an instance of `OuterClass`, since each instance might have a different type parameter. However, you want to pass an `InnerTrait` as parameter to `OuterClass` constructor, so you'll need to construct `InnerTrait` before `OuterClass`. But since `InnerTrait` has to be tied to an instance of `OuterClass`, then `OuterClass` must be constructed before `InnerClass`, turning this into a chicken & egg problem.

There's something strange with that design, so I suggest you rethink it through.